# Export aspx web pages to pdf and download

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I am having some problem when trying to export an aspx page as pdf and download them. Here is the codes:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(url)))
        {
            String line = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Text2PDF(line);
        }
    }

    protected void Text2PDF(string PDFText)
    {
        //HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(PDFText);

        //Create PDF document 
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        HTMLWorker parser = new HTMLWorker(document);

        string PDF_FileName = Server.MapPath("MyFirstPdf.pdf");
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(PDF_FileName, FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();

        try
        {
            parser.Parse(reader);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Display parser errors in PDF. 
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Error!" + ex.Message);
            Chunk text = paragraph.Chunks[0] as Chunk;
            if (text != null)
            {
                text.Font.Color = BaseColor.RED;
            }
            document.Add(paragraph);
        }
        finally
        {
            document.Close();
            DownLoadPdf(PDF_FileName);
        }
    }
    private void DownLoadPdf(string PDF_FileName)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(PDF_FileName);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    }
```

However, when I click the button, nothing happens. The browser does not prompt me to download as well. I wonder why. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the trigger to your aspx file. If not please add the trigger as a example

```
<Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: And i believe you are using UpdatePanel inside your page

Comment: You mean add the lines above after I declared my button in aspx file. Nope I did not use any update panel

Comment: That is up to you since you have to use appropriate code for create pdf file

Comment: Use itext sharp. For more details look at this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387352/how-to-create-the-pdf-file-from-the-htm-page-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp